# Android Studio 3.5 y Apply Code Changes

Tags: android, android-studio

Actuyalize mi Android Studio a la versión 3.5 y tengo deshabilitada la opción **"Apply Code Changes"**.

Estoy realizando pruebas en mi dispositivo Android 6.0 (API 19).

**Android Studio me dice que necesita una API 26 como mínimo**. Esto significa que no podré realizar dicha acción con mi móvil o hay alguna opción de solucionar esto?

---

[image: Esto es lo que me dice Android Studio 3.5]

Por eso creo que el problema es que necesito un dispositivo más nuevo, pero me parece raro que quiten esa característica tan importante para el desarrollo

Comment: "API 26 como mínimo" se debe a que realizaste algún cambio en el código, recuerdas que cambiaste?.

Comment: El problema no es el código por lo que interpreto. El problema es que mi dispositivo móvil es API 19 y aparentemente requiere API 26 o mayor para poderse utilizar Apply Code Changes. Pero me parece raro que quiten una opción tan importante como esa. Mi celular es un Samsung J7 con Android 6.0.1 y me dice que no es compatible

Answer (score 0):

El problema se puede determinar en base a lo descrito en la [documentación oficial de **Apply Code Changes**](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes-requirements)

> [**Apply Code Changes**](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes-requirements) :En Android Studio 3.5 y versiones
>   posteriores, Apply Changes le permite enviar cambios de código y
>   recursos a su aplicación en ejecución sin reiniciar su aplicación y,
>   en algunos casos, sin reiniciar la actividad actual.

Si revisas los requerimientos para [Apply Code Changes](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes-requirements)

- Construir el APK de su aplicación utilizando una variante de compilación de depuración.
- **Implementar su aplicación en un dispositivo o emulador de destino que ejecuta Android 8.0 (API nivel 26) o superior.**

Por lo tanto **si estas usando un emulador (`AVD`) o dispositivo físico con Android 6.0 (API 19), no te permitirá usar esta opción.**